# Select only explicit value/regexp

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to select a specific value from my column.  Probably It should be done by regexp function, but I have been having some problems with that...

Column name: Column1

```
Value1: 'Value\sdf90df\015'
Value2: 'Value\f213jdj\012'
Value3: 'Value\kjsd2ej\031'
```

Is there some way to select only: sdf90df, f213jdj, kjsd2ej?

Comment: What is your RDBMs ? You want to retrieve just those values or you want to filter a column by It ?

Comment: I'm working on oracle dtbase

Comment: Here you got a simple solution with no regular expressions: `SUBSTR(tab.col1,INSTR(tab.col1,'\',1,1)+1,INSTR(tab.col1,'\',1,2)-(INSTR(tab.col1,'\',1,1)+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this version.

```
select regexp_replace( Column1, '.+\\([^\\]+)\\.+', '\1' )
  from yourTable
```

What I'm doing is selecting your Column1 with a function that does a replace based on a regular expression `regexp_replace`

The regular expression I used is `.+\\([^\\]+)\\.+` breaking it you have:

`.+\\` - this gets everything until find a `\` we use two `\\` because it need to be scaped.

`([^\\]+)` - This portion is whithin parenthesis to be understood as a capturing group (I will talk about it later) I'm saying here get everything that isn't a `\`

And

`\\.+` get a dash and everything else

The `regexp_replace` as I'm using it has this parameters: `regexp_replace(source, regex, replacement)` so in my replacement I used the string `\1` which means get from that regular expression just the group 1

So, your string is `'Value\sdf90df\015'` breaking it on the regular expression you have:

`Value\` then `sdf90df` which is group 1 (because of the parentesis) and then `\015`

On the first version of this answer I've used `$1` thats because some regular expression processors use it insted of `\1` but for oracle the right one is `\NUMBER` to specify a capturing group.

Hope the explanation had clarify your doubts.

Comment: hmm, I don't understand, All what i want is just select 3 random values. In this case: sdf90d,f213jdj,kjsd2ej

Comment: You need to select those values in just one column?

Comment: Nope, Output should looks:
asdsdd,
3434fd,
213dsd   I want to select only values between Value\    and \number

Comment: oooh, I've added the wrong parameter. The right one is \1 I will edit and add some information.

Comment: @maciek2791 Take a look now! I may clarify better.

Comment: Thanks Jorge! You are the best ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `regex_substr()`.  Something like this:

```
select replace(regex_substr(column1, '[\\][^\\]+[\\]', 0, 2), '\\', '')
```

Comment: I deciced to use substr function.